# Android with pthread_cancel enabled? ffmpeg depends on pthread_cancel

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, rtsp-client

I am building ffmpeg 2.1.3 in the android with ndk r9b version.

I have used the below command.

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/home/fbuild 
             --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- 
             --enable-cross-compile 
             --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-gpl 
             --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags=-I/home/fbuild/include 
             --extra-ldflags=-L/home/fbuild/lib --disable-doc 
             --disable-ffmpeg --enable-network --disable-ffplay 
             --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avresample 
             --enable-decoders 
             --enable-encoders 
             --enable-muxers 
             --enable-demuxers 
             --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters 
             --enable-avresample --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi 
             --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-libx264 
             --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5 --enable-runtime-cpudetect  
             --cpu=cortex-a8 
             --enable-pthreads --enable-static
```

in config.log

```
 main:ffconf.82qqjSTF.c(.text+0x4): error: undefined reference to '**pthread_cancel**
```

Which clearly indicates, pthread_cancel is unavailable.

Is it an existing issue, or do we have a any other solution for the same ?

I have enabled '--enable-pthreads',

I am trying to stream RTSP Stream through, UDP

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Is it an existing issue?**

The official NDK documentation states that:

> `pthread_cancel()` will not be supported in Bionic, because doing this would involve making the C library significantly bigger for very little benefit. [...] All of this is contrary to the Bionic design goals. If your code depends on thread cancellation, please consider alternatives.

*see the Bionic Overview section*

That being said ffmpeg configure script auto detects this:

```
if enabled pthreads; then
  check_func pthread_cancel
fi
```

So I assume ffmpeg has fallbacks on the implementation side if `pthread_cancel` is not available (see the `#if HAVE_PTHREAD_CANCEL` sections).